# Lenovo Ideapad is never charged to 100%, and the charger cannot be detected immediately

Tags: lenovo, battery, charging

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 onto my Lenovo Ideapad 3. When I plug in the charge, the laptop cannot detect the charger and get charged right away, it will however detect it and start the process 30 seconds later. Same goes to unplugging the charger, it cannot detect the unplug of the charger until 30 seconds later.

The other thing is the power can never go exceeds 98%.

Does anyone know the solution to fix this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Ubuntu. You can check for and install an UEFI update. It may change that behavior or it may not if said behavior is by design.

Comment: @ChanganAuto how do i install an UEFI update on Lenovo?

Comment: Check the support page for your specific model and follow instructions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by unplugging the charger and draining the battery to 0%.